# How to create an Array with a single element or an array of elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

In several languages, it is pretty common to write a method that accepts either an array, or a single object:

Ex in Ruby:

```
def sum(array_or_single_element)
  # converts into array if single element, remains the same otherwise
  array = Array(array_or_single_element)
  array.reduce(:+)
end
```

I have the feeling Lodash is here to provide this type of utilities to JS. But it doesn't provide such method.

- Is it really absent?
- Is is so ovbious in JS (in which case I missed it) so that it doesn't need to be in the framework?

I don't really like writing

```
if (typeof array === 'Array') {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), like this

```
console.log([].concat(0));
// [ 0 ]
console.log([].concat([1, 2, 3]));
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log([].concat("thefourtheye"));
// [ 'thefourtheye' ]
```

We concatenate all the elements we want, with an empty array. So, even if our original data is just a single element, it will be a part of a new array.

Comment: Nice, didn't know concat could work with single element!